# Apollo client cache with SSR

Tags: next.js, apollo, server-side-rendering, apollo-client

I am using @apollo/client with Next.js Server Side Rendering. The data I am fetching is from wp-graphql, and therefore it is crucial to have them rendered on server side. There is just one slight issue, the cache is forever. I either have to reset the cache every x minutes:

```
setInterval(async () => {
  await client.resetStore();
}, 60_000);
```

or specify the no-cache policy

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://the.url",
  cache: new InMemoryCache({}),

  // For no cache, which is slow
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      errorPolicy: "ignore",
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      errorPolicy: "all",
    },
  },
});
```

Is there any better way to do this, while still using SSR?

Comment: Solved it by specifying the apollo client in the [[slug]].tsx, and in the getServerSide props checking if the path is api/emptyCache it runs client.resetStore(). This way it works as intended.